# What does this syntax mean which likes `functionName: {}`?

Tags: javascript

I have found a piece of code in my company's project like the following:

```
while(condition){        
        code...

        reloop: {
            if(somethingIsTrue) {
                break reloop;
            }
        }

        code...
}
```

I don't understand what `reloop` does, can anyone give a simple explanation?

Comment: It's a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: ...and `break` allows you to break out of a label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: It's also the JavaScript equivalent of a Goto... scary bad (IMHO)

Comment: @JECarterII: it's not really a `goto` since won't go anywhere you're not at already (inside a loop). in the code shown, it doesn't appear that the statement does anything at all since you can't break non-loop "blocks".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reloop:` is a `label`. They are rarely used, and serve a very specific purpose: they let you `break` or `continue` **outer** loops from **inner** loops.

The article on MDN [about labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) explains this better.

Note that labels are **very rarely used**, and most of the time **needing a label hints that your code is unclear, and should be restructured**. I have never, not even once, used a label in `javascript`.

Avoid them unless they are truly the only clean solution to piece of code that proves difficult to write. Prefer, instead, splitting code into functions that you can `return` from.

Answer (score 2):

`reloop` is a label for the block. The `break` command breaks out of the labelled block.

See eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break